# soap request is returning this data

Tags: iphone, soap

when i am hitting this link in soap webservice getting the response of The 'soap:Envelope' start tag on line 1 does not match the end tag of 'soapody'.

http://74.54.137.138:3052/Service.asmx?op=GetFlightDetailforSQAR

2:10 PMrecevedstring---> soaperverServer was unable to process request. --->

The 'soap:Envelope' start tag on line 1 does not match the end tag of 'soapody'. Line 1, position 343.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code with your code:

> -(void) createconnection
>      {

```
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];

   NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
                     "<soap:Body>"
                     "<GetFlightDetailforSQAR xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"
                     "<FlightNo>100</FlightNo>"
                     "<UserBadgeNo>500</UserBadgeNo>"
                     "</GetFlightDetailforSQAR>"
                     "</soap:Body>"
                     "</soap:Envelope>"];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://74.54.137.138:3052/Service.asmx?op=GetFlightDetailforSQAR"];

   NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];
   [req addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
   [req addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetFlightDetailforSQAR" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
   [req addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
   [req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [req setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

   conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
   if (conn) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  } 
      [pool release];
}
```

- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
  {

  NSLog(@"found file and started parsing");

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict

{

NSLog(@"START ELEMENT :%@",elementName);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string

{

```
NSLog(@"String %@",string);
```

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName

{

NSLog(@"END ELEMENT :%@",elementName);

}